# Fibonacci function

Tags: r, fibonacci

We have been given a task, which we just can't figure out:

Write an R function which will generate a vector containing the first n
terms of the Fibonacci sequence. The steps in this are as follows:
(a) Create the vector to store the result in.
(b) Initialize the first two elements.
(c) Run a loop with i running from 3 to n, filling in the i-th element

Work so far:

```
vast=function(n){
 vast=vector()
 vast[1]=1
 vast[2]=1
 for(i in 3){vast[i]=vast[i-1]+vast[i-2]}
 }
```

All we end up is with the error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable  ??

How are we supposed to generate the wanted function?

Comment: 1. Give your vector a different name than the function. 2. Make your vector the correct type and size when you create it: `fib = numeric(n)`.

Comment: Initialize `vast <- rep(NA, n)` and loop correctly `for (i in 3:n)`.

Comment: A hint to your second question: google. Just 5 sec with it gave me several different options.

Comment: If you want to annoy your teacher use the closed form ;) (usually they try to teach recursion with the fibonacci example)

Comment: There's a lot of invalid `R` code here, so you may want to go back and get more familiar with the basic syntax.  But most of your problem appears to come from a lack of understanding of software code in general, rather than anything specific to `R` .

Comment: +1 for showing your work.  +infinity if you indicate to your teacher that you got help on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're also closer than you think.  If you simply add `return(vast)` as the last line you'll get the answer back (except that `n` is ignored, so you'll only get the first three terms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My vote's on closed form as @bdecaf suggested (because it would annoy your teacher):

```
vast = function(n) round(((5 + sqrt(5)) / 10) * (( 1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (1:n - 1))
```

But you can fix the code you already have with two minor changes:

```
vast=function(n){
 vast=vector()
 vast[1]=1
 vast[2]=1
 for(i in 3:n){vast[i]=vast[i-1]+vast[i-2]}
 return(vast)
 }
```

I would still follow some of the suggestions already given--especially using different names for your vector and your function, but the truth is there are lots of different ways to accomplish your goal.  For one thing, it really isn't necessary to initialize an empty vector at all in this instance, since we can use `for` loops in R to expand the vector as you were already doing.  You could do the following, for instance:

```
vast=function(n){
  x = c(1,1)
  for(i in 3:n) x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
  return(x)
}
```

Of course, we all have things to learn about programming, but that's why we're here.  We all got help from someone at some point and we all get better as we help others to improve as well.

**UPDATE:** As @Carl Witthoft points out, it is a best practice to initialize the vector to the appropriate size when that size is known in order save time and space, so another way to accomplish this task would be:

```
vast=function(n) {
  x = numeric(n)
  x[1:2] = c(1,1)
  for(i in 3:n) x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: In general you're better off preallocating the *entire* vector. This saves not only time (as expanding every time thru the loop is a lot of operations) but space (since the vector gets copied internally as it's expanded).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You're definitely right, and I believe that people should learn best practices as early as possible.  My point here is that there are different ways that will work, and really, for the Fibonacci sequence, very rarely would anyone be interested in generating a large enough sequence that the space and time savings will create a practically meaningful difference, but I'll update to highlight best practices.